# Why the space have to be complex in the spectral theorem for bounded self-adjoint operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

In the spectral theorem for **compact self-adjoint** linear operators $T:H\to H$ (as stated in [Conway's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ccEGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22The+Diagonalization+of+Compact+Self-Adjoint+Operators%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ4vHRsJbiAhUiHrkGHY-yAJoQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Diagonalization%20of%20Compact%20Self-Adjoint%20Operators%22&f=false)), the Hilbert space $H$ can be real or complex.

However, in the spectral theorem for **bounded self-adjoint** linear operators $T:H\to H$ (as stated in [Bachman's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wCHtLumoGY4C&pg=PA450&lpg=PA450&dq=%22Now,+for+the+first+time,+we+obtain+a+spectral+theorem+for+an+operator%22&source=bl&ots=vwRafTwk7p&sig=ACfU3U3R3lYY8Ll_LB-U7y1H6L5NI9vRXA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj98cG_t5biAhUVH7kGHU5CDDYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Now%2C%20for%20the%20first%20time%2C%20we%20obtain%20a%20spectral%20theorem%20for%20an%20operator%22&f=false)), the Hilbert space $H$ have to be complex.

Is this assumption really needed? Is there any version for **bounded self-adjoint** linear operators defined on **real spaces**?

Comment: I guess for a real Hilbert space H, you can always complexify it to get a complex Hilbert space K and extend the your operator to be defined on K. After this extension, your operator should still be self-adjoint, then you can apply the spectral theory.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638216/spectral-theorem-for-unbounded-self-adjoint-operators-on-real-hilbert-spaces